# cond variable has no value

Tags: syntax, lisp, common-lisp

I am a newbie in lisp. 
I just want to create a short programme.
It is about testing a condition and do something when it is true.
So if 3 modulo 2 is not true (what obviously is not true) I want to print the result of 7+9+11.
I get the error *** - COND: variable /= has no value.

I already tried to change the cond to a when. But it didn't work and I get the same error.

(cond (/= 0 (mod 3 2 ))

do (+ 7 9 11)

)

I expect 27 as the result and not an error.

Comment: Hi, here is an explanation of COND for Common Lisp: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm#cond
If you are using another Lisp dialect, they probably have some documentation, too.

Comment: If you are new to Lisp, then it might be useful to read a basic introduction. See here for a basic tutorial book you can download: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: Thanks, I did a few tutorials in lisp. I passed them well, but i really don't understand my mistake in this code. I tried the modulo thing and it worked and I tried the addition and it also worked. The syntax is correct, I don't understand why my code isn't working.

Comment: what kind of Lisp are you using?

Comment: Hint: the syntax is not, in fact correct.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to enter in a program like this.

```lisp
(if (/= 0 (mod 3 2))
    (+ 7 9 11))
```

Here, `if` has a syntax like

```lisp
(if (PREDICATE)
    (RETURN-IF-PREDICATE-TRUE)
    (RETURN-IF-PREDICATE-FALSE))
```

where `RETURN-IF-PREDICATE-FALSE` defaults to `nil` if not provided.

If you would prefer to use `cond`, then you can do

```lisp
(cond
  ((/= 0 (mod 3 2)) (+ 7 9 11)))
```

Here, `cond` has a syntax like

```lisp
(cond
  ((P1) (R1))
  ((P2) (R2))
  ...
)
```

where if predicate `P1` is true, then `R1` is returned. Otherwise the next predicate is tested, and so on.

If your code, your `cond` is missing a few parentheses. Generically, you are doing

```lisp
;; (incorrect code)
(cond
  (P1) do (+ 7 9 11))
```

which is missing parentheses around the predicate-result pair and around the do-macro.

Also, there is no reason to use `do` here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood my mistake, but now I have another question. I tried to insert my character into loop, but it says that a has no value. I don't understand it because the loop declares about a. Why is there no value for a?    
(loop for a from 1 to 20)
                                                                                                                              
       (cond
                                                                                                                                         
  ((/= 0 (mod a 2)) (+ 7 9 11)))

Comment: @Arenosa Although this is a second question, you again have parentheses problems. You close your loop parentheses --- outside of which `a` has no meaning. For more, you might consider asking another question